# Density of integers with many divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

By Dirchlet's hyperbola method, one can prove that the average number of divisors of integers $1 \leq n \leq X$ is $\log X$. This question concerns the number of integers $n \leq X$ such that the number of divisors, $d(n)$, is substantially larger than average. Indeed, what is known about the size of the set

$$\displaystyle \{1 \leq n \leq X : d(n) > (\log X)^A \}$$

where $A > 1$ is considered to be a large (but fixed) positive number?

Comment: Karl K. Norton, "On the frequencies of large values of divisor functions", Acta Arithmetica 68:3 (1994), 219-244. See http://eudml.org/doc/206657

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Theorem 1.11 and Theorem 1.22 of the paper by Norton, cited in the comment of Peter Humphries, show that for any fixed $A \ge \log 2$,
$$
\frac{X (\log\log X)^{O(1)}}{(\log X)^{B(A)}}  \ll_A 
|\{1\le n\le X:d(n) \ge (\log X)^A\}| \ll_A \frac{X}{(\log X)^{B(A)}},
$$
where
$$
B(A):=1+\frac{A}{\log 2}\left(\log\left(\frac{A}{\log 2}\right) -1 \right).
$$
Equation (1.37) of the same paper gives the correct order of magnitude: For every fixed $A>\log 2$,
$$ 
|\{1\le n\le X:d(n) \ge (\log X)^A\}| \asymp_A \frac{X}{(\log X)^{B(A)} (\log\log X)^{1/2}}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

The normal order of $\log(d(n))$ is $\log(2)\log\log(n))$.  So, for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\log(d(n))<(1+\epsilon)\log(2)\log(\log(n))
$$
hold for almost all n: that is, if the proportion of $n\le x$ for which this does not hold tends to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity.  Thus
$$
d(n) < \log(n)^{(1+\epsilon)\log(2)}
$$
holds for almost all $n$.

Comment: Is it possible to give an explicit bound for the number of such $n$?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao 'proportion... tends to 0' does not mean finitely many, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the density of such numbers as a function of $X$. For example can one obtain a bound of $O_A(X(\log X)^{-B(A)})$ for some number $B(A)$ depending on $A$?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Of course; good question but I don't know.